# Adding/override one image to another image at specific position?

Tags: java, image, jai

I want to add an image to another image at specific position either it would be pixels or cm or (x,y). I have to do it by java programming using JAI(Java Advanced Imaging).
I googled to get sample code.
I got replacing ,adding at the end only.But not at specific position.
Any idea is appreciatable.
Laxman chowdary

Comment: So, what have you tried?  Do you have any sample code??

Comment: [Replace Image](http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/69743/69610/showthread.aspx).... I used this link for replacing one image with another image.

Comment: So, you're trying to overlay two images in a Word Document using Apose?

Comment: I just want to override part of the image at specific location with other image using JAVA...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BufferedImage sourceImage = ImageIO.read("myImage");
BufferedImage overlayImage = ImageIO.read("myOverlay");

Graphics2D g2Source = sourceImage.createGraphics();
g2Source.drawImage(overlayImage, x, y, null);

g2Source.dispose();
```

Comment: drawImage(overlayImage, x, y) is not defined.. how to use it?

Comment: Use drawImage(img, x, y, null) All drawImage needs as last parameter a optional ImageObserver

Comment: @polypiel Thanks for the catch, typed right into the answer box :P